# Show selected Option in dropdown using select2()

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I have two dropdown select boxes, I am using AngularJS to show options in the dropdown.

In my Script when i use `$(".select2_demo_1").select2();` only one dropdown shows selected option at a time. I want to show both dropdowns to show selected options. Kindly need help.

```
<select id="one" class="select2_demo_1 form-control" ng-model="orgs" ng-options="item.OrganizationTypeTitle for item in organization"></select>
<select id="two" class="select2_demo_1 form-control" ng-model="industry" ng-options="i.IndustryTypeTitle for i in industries"></select>

var getOrganizationTypes = OrgService.getOrganizationTypes();

getOrganizationTypes.then(function (response) {
    $scope.organization = response.data;
    $scope.orgs = $scope.organization[0];

}, function () {
    alert('can not get Organization Types!');
});

var getIndustryTypes = OrgService.getIndustryTypes();

getIndustryTypes.then(function (response) {

    $scope.industries = response.data;
    $scope.industry = $scope.industries[0];

}, function () {

    alert('can not get industry types');

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop for getting value from same css

```
      $(function () { 
        var v = [];
        $(".select2_demo_1").each(function(){
            v.push($(this).val());
        })  
      });
```

Sample : [Demo On jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ch1opkqe/)

```
<link href="http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-3.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-3.2/select2.js"></script>    


        <select  class="select2_demo_1" name="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations" >
            <option value="1" selected>1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>



        <select  class="select2_demo_1" name="drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations" >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected>2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>


<button class="getValue">Get Value</button>
<button  class="setValue"> Set  value </button>



$(".getValue").click(function() {
           var v = [];
        $(".select2_demo_1").each(function(){       
            v.push($(this).val());
            alert($(this).val())
        })  
    });
```